# jQuery click event is not working in first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I using a code on my page. Like this:

```
$('#language_id').change(function () {
    var urli = 'https://example.com/php/get_arch.php?language_id=' + language_id;
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: urli,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(response){
        var options = '';
        $.each(response.archs, function() {
            options += '<option value="' + this.arch_id + '">' + this.name + '</option>';
        });
        $('#arch_id').html('<option value="0">- ' + selachitecture + ' -</option>'+options);
        $('#arch_id').attr('disabled', false);
      }
    });
});

$('#arch_id').change(function(){
var version_id = $('#version_id :selected').val();
    $('#selectBoxInfo').load('https://example.com/dl.php?fileName=' + arch_id + "&lang=" + lang);
    return(false);
});
$('body').on('click', '.buttond a', function() { 
    alert("new link clicked!");
    $("a").removeAttr("onclick");
});
```

I explain my code: when selecting an optional, it will create a button "Download". This button load by Ajax. I don't want feature pop-up of this button.
So, I tried to prevent this button turn on the pop-up.
The problem is: at first click in button, my Javascript is not working. It only works from the second click.

I don't know problem at here. I using 'on' to listen to all event.

Comment: Can you show the content when load `https://example.com/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**replace your code with this code ..**

```
    $('#selectBoxInfo')
      .load('https://example.com/dl.php?fileName=' + arch_id+"&lang="+lang
      ,function(){
        $("a").removeAttr("onclick");
      }
     );
```